# WEC7 Compiling Boost (ARMV4I)

Tags: c++, boost, windows-ce

I'm currently try to build boost thread, system and date_time for windows embedded compact 7. I have get the paths working but at this time a have a compilation error which seems to be caused by "codeanalysis\sourceannotation.h" but i dont know why I shall have this and for what this is needed?!

can anyone explain me what this header is and why is it needed?

Is there anymore who was successful in building boost for wec7 and x86 oder armv4i?

EDIT:

build batch:

```
@echo off
cls
bjam toolset=msvc-9.0~CEPlatformName -a --layout=system --address-model=32 --with-system --with-filesystem --with-date_time --with-thread variant=release threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared
```

CEPlattformName.bat:
    @echo off
    echo BOOST FOR WINCE 7 Armv4i
    echo.

```
rem ------------------------------------------------------------
set BOOST_DIR="E:\boost\boost_1_42_0"
set PLATFORM=WINCE
set TARGETCPU=Armv4i
set OSVERSION=CE700
rem ------------------------------------------------------------

REM if not %1==%&TARGETCPU% goto error

echo Setting Boost directory to %BOOST_DIR%
echo Setting OS Platform to %PLATFORM%
echo Setting target CPU to %TARGETCPU%
echo Setting OS Version to %OSVERSION%

rem setting visual studio 2008 variable path
set SDKROOT="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\"

set PLATFORMROOT=%SDKROOT%\%PLATFORM%_%OSVERSION%\
set INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\WINCE_CE700\Include\Armv4i";%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce7\include;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce7\atlmfc\include
set LIB=%PLATFORMROOT%\lib\%TARGETCPU%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce7\ATLMFC\LIB\%TARGETCPU%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce7\LIB\%TARGETCPU%
set PATH=%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE;%VSINSTALLDIR%\VC\ce\bin\x86_arm;%VSINSTALLDIR%\VC\bin;%PATH%
rem set LIB=%STLPORT_LIB%;%PLATFORMROOT%\lib\%TARGETCPU%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce\ATLMFC\LIB\%TARGETCPU%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce\LIB\%TARGETCPU%

echo %PATH%
echo PATH at %PATH%
echo PLATFORMROOT at %PLATFORMROOT%
echo.

echo INCLUDE is %INCLUDE%
echo.

echo LIB is %LIB%
echo.

goto exit

:error
echo Invald Target CPU
goto exit

:exit
echo Successful
```

user-config.jam:

```
using msvc : 9.0~CEPlatformName : "cl.exe" :
    <compileflags>-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    <compileflags>-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
    <compileflags>-DBOOST_PROTO_MAX_ARITY=10
    <compileflags>-DBOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
    <compileflags>-DBOOST_MPL_LIMIT_METAFUNCTION_ARITY=10
    <compileflags>-D_WIN32_WCE=0x700
    <compileflags>-DUNDER_CE
    <compileflags>-DWINCE
    <compileflags>-DARM
    <compileflags>-D_ARM_
    <compileflags>-DARMV4I
    <compileflags>-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    <compileflags>-D_UNICODE
    <compileflags>-DUNICODE
    <compileflags>-D_MSC_VER=1500
    <linkflags>/subsystem:windowsce,7.00 
    <linkflags>/MACHINE:THUMB
    <linkflags>/NODEFAULTLIB:oldnames.lib
    <linkflags>/NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib
    <linkflags>coredll.lib
    <linkflags>corelibc.lib
    <linkflags>ole32.lib
    <linkflags>oleaut32.lib
    <linkflags>uuid.lib
    <linkflags>commctrl.lib
    <architecture>arm
    <instruction-set>armv4
    <interface>wince
    <setup>CEPlatformName.bat;
```

regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add which compilation error you received? Other things that can help folks help you is to provide code snippets. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\CE700\Include\Armv4i\sal.h(942) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h': No such file or directory`

This is my error which came up. I edit the question with the all scripts which I use.